# Need help in inserting content of arraylist to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using sqlite database. I used the following code to store three values in a database.

```
sampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME
                + " (rowid INT , songname VARCHAR," + "  count INT);");
        int len = songlist.size();
        Log.v("songlist len", Integer.toString(len));
        for (int s = 0; s < songlist.size(); s++) {         

             sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
             " Values (1,"+songlist.get(s)+",1);");



            Log.v("After insert", "1");
        }
```

And I get the following error

```
01-13 20:58:08.903: E/AndroidRuntime(593): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: android: INSERT INTO freq Values (1,android,1);
```

Need help.

Comment: try using "<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149438/tool-to-see-android-database-tables-and-data>" sqlite3 to debug your database

Comment: i love this kind of question ... it's a sample of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation ...it seems like you start android programming  without understanding android basics: simply yo're using `openOrCreateDatabase`, this function is creating new OR OPENING already created db ... asuming that you've already run this program on test device/emulator db was created and table was added ... but this table had different columns (since you add new one while you've been "developing" your app) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Maybe you will have to add quotes for string entry
`Values (1,\""+songlist.get(s)+"\",1);");`

Comment: not may be. you always have to put quotes. but you'd rather use ContentValues, which does the escaping for you.